# Issue with Solr Delete command

Tags: solr

What does this command do in Solr?

```
curl --negotiate -k -u : 'https://solrurl:8983/solr/collectionname_solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"delete":{"query":"/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/folder_d/folder_e/folder_f/folder_g/"}}'
```

Comment: Not much by itself; depending on the default query parser it might delete documents that match parts or all of the path in the default field. What are you trying to debug / find out?